# Bind boolean to a label based on user's selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am designing a page in which informs a manager whether an applicant requires a work permit. For this I have created a data table called "Countries" that contains a string field "countries" and a boolean "EU_member". If the country is a member of the European Union the boolean is true and vice-versa.

I have set up a dropdown field in the page from which the manager can select the country. I now want to bind a label to the boolean field, so that it shows whether the country is part of the European Union or not. Right now, it is only bound to the country field.

```
@datasources.Countries.query.filters.country._equals=Dropdown1.value;
```

My second idea was to include a server script that is triggered by the onValueEdit method of the dropdown field

```
function checkWorkPermit(widgetValue) {
  var query = app.models.Countries.newQuery();
  query.filters.country._equals = widgetValue;
  var records = query.run();
  return records[0].EU_Member;
}
```

but the console returns

checkWorkPermit is not defined at ....Panel8.Dropdown1.onValueEdit:1:1

Comment: Client side vs server side? I believe you need to use `google.script.run.<function name>` to call server scripts from the client pages.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to resolve this issue. My server script works in the console

`code function checkWorkPermit(countryName) {
  if (countryName !== null) {
    var query = app.models.Countries.newQuery();
    query.filters.country._equals = countryName;
    var result = query.run();
    if (result[0].EU_Member === false) {
      console.log(...);
    } else {
      console.log(...);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Please select a country');
  }`

I now want to return the result to a label, but I am not very familiar with appmaker and widgets.

Comment: Post the solution to the original question as an answer, and accept it. Ask a new question if your new question is not already answered by a review of documentation or existing asked questions. **Do not** post code in comments, or change the question you are asking in comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering, that the dropdown's `options` property is bound to smth like this:

```javascript
@datasources.Countries.items
```

binding for the label could look similar to this:

```javascript
@pages.MyPage.descendants.CountriesDropDown.value.EU_member ?
    'Work permit is required' :
    'Work permit is NOT required'
```